# REST API GET Call Filter

Tags: rest, business-process-management

Hi I am very new to REST API calls & need some help. My REST API GET call is returning me 100 records and I would like to get records based on some condition. How can I put my condition to check fr those specific records and return me only that. Thanks.Below is the REST API I am calling and would to filter on the results.

```
Sample Method Invocation
GET /rest/bpm/wle/v1/exposed/{type}
Parameters
None.
Request Content
None.
Response Content
Exposed Items list (ExposedItems complexType).
The default content-type is application/json.
```

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: You probably want to mention and tag that this is IBM BPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IBM BPM product provides a REST API that can be used by client applications.  This REST API is architected, designed and implemented by IBM and you can't change it .... only use it.  Some of the exposed APIs have filter capabilities associated with them ... most notably the task and process instance queries.  The specific API you listed does not have a filter associated.  What that means is that you must execute the request and you will get back a JSON object that represents all the exposed instances.  Now that you have the array of instances, you will be responsible for "filtering" them yourself.  This can be achieved by walking through the array and asking each element if it matches your criteria.  If it does, add it to a new list.  If it doesn't, ignore it.  At the end, you will have a new list that will be a subset of the original list.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I understood it.